# How to check if product is created from SOAP

Tags: soap-api-v2, magento1.9.2.3

I am using 3rd party Inventory System (I can not modify). The products are saved from this 3rd party system to Magento. I would like to perform some actions on product before it gets saved from this system. How would I?